# Android Studio 2.1 - I want font antialiasing / smoothing off

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts, font-smoothing

On Windows 7 64 bit in **Android Studio 1.5** I have a nice Monospaced 14 font **without** antialiasing / smoothing which I like. However, in recently installed **Android Studio 2.1** (all settings allegedly imported from AS 1.5) - antialiasing / smoothing is applied to my font. How to turn it off?  Thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution? I am lost as well. antialiased fonts with this pixel size and size look just dirty.

Comment: I did not...  still using AS 1.5 for the reason. Let's wait for some solution...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer. Android Studio 2.0 added antialiasing setting:

[image]

Comment: This setting made the default font appear "bold", which is somewhat undesirable

Comment: Hmm.  I am using Monospaced 14 which looks perfect, not bold.